# How to get value of elements without using IDs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

Lets say I had the following code:

```
<div class="post">
  <h2 itemprop="name">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">The Post Title</a>
  </h2>
<div class="details">
  <span>
    <em class="date">Jul 17, 2014  </em>
  </span>
  <span>
    Category:  
    <a href="/category/staff-profile/">Staff Profile</a> 
  </span>
</div>
```

How would I possibly get the values of "The Post Title" and "Staff Profile" using JavaScript without changing the HTML on the page at all? i.e. I couldn't use getElementbyID for example. I could use jQuery if I had to but would rather not if possible.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: There are many DOM traversal methods. I recommend to start learning about the DOM via http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Comment: How about using `getElementsByClassName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get these values using `getElementsByTagName` which returns an array

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML // returns The Post Title
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].innerHTML // returns Staff Profile
```

If these links are the first ones you can use indexes 0 and 1, otherwise you should look for the right index

#### Update

Another way that may be simple is to select these links inside the div with the class `post`

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("post")[index].getElementsByTagName("a");
links[0].innerHTML; // returns The Post Title
links[1].innerHTML; // returns Staff Profile
```

This solution would be the best one if the index of the div with the class `post` doesn't change

Comment: Probably better to cache the result of `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` instead of doing it twice though.

Comment: You're right ! but I want it to make it easy for the OP

Comment: I like this solution, it seems simple, however my problem is that in my real life example the content appears on a very dynamic page where those values would change from page to page unfortunately. i.e. sometimes it will be [20] and another might be [25].

Comment: @Mhoad you've also failed to state in what form you actually want this information.  In my answer I've assumed you want an array of URL/title pairs.

Comment: My bad, I want them in a string value.

Comment: @Mhoad, check the update, may be this solution would be the best if the index of the div with class `post` doesn't change

Comment: Thank you so much Khalid, that works perfectly for my solution!

Answer (score 3):

For a jQuery based expression you can use this:

```
$('a').map(function() {
    return [this.href, this.textContent];
}).get();
```

which should return:

```
[ [ 'http://www.example.com', 'The Post Title' ],
  [ 'http://sitename/category/staff-profile/', 'Staff Profile' ] ]
```

Should you specifically want the original relative URLs instead of the normalised full URLs, use `this.getAttribute(href)` in place of `this.href`

For a pure (ES5) equivalent:

```
[].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function (el) {
    return [el.href, el.textContent];
});
```

Older browsers that don't support the W3C standard `.textContent` property may require the `.innerText` property instead, e.g.:

```
return [el.href, el.textContent || el.innerText];
```

Comment: he said he'd rather not use jQuery.

Comment: @ajp15243 Barmar posted his comment about 2s before I added that edit

Comment: @Alnitak Ah, I forgot that edits soon after first posting an answer won't go into the edit history.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
var posts = document.querySelector('.post');

for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    var title = links[0].innerText || links[0].textContent;
    var profile = links[1].innerText || links[1].textContent;
}
```

Comment: Regarding jQuery, he said: _would rather not if possible_

Comment: This is probably wrong, it'll return all of the text as one blob rather than as individual strings.

Comment: To be fair.. the question is pretty odd.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a more modern browser, you can use document.querySelectorAll() which takes in CSS style selector syntax.

```
var aList = document.querySelectorAll('.post a');
for (var i = 0; i < aList.length; ++i) {
  alert(aList[i].innerHTML);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pq9x457/)

I used '.post a' rather than just 'a' because I assume your page may have other 'a' tags in it that you don't necessarily want.